# What breaker size and wire gauge should I use for a new garage outlet circuit?

Tags: garage

I would like to add some much-needed electrical outlets in my garage. As of right now it seems like the power that's going to the garage door opener and the garage light is also on the same line as some kitchen lights and some bedroom lights and Outlets. I feel like that circuit is already pushed to its maximum and would like to install a new circuit breaker and run a new line and pull the Garage items off of their old line and attach them onto a new one including my four new Outlets. I have pretty good electrical skills although that is not my profession. Just wondering what size breaker I need to install as well as is there a specific Gauge that I need to use from the breaker out. I'm using 14 2 on my Outlets that I'm adding.

For reference I've moved my washer and dryer about 3 months ago and I rewired a new wire to the breaker myself so I have a pretty good idea of how to do it just not sure of the specific sizes to use. I have several open areas for new circuit breakers.

Comment: If you used 14-2 for your outlets you will need 15 A breaker. If you use 12-2 for the whole circuit you can use 20 A breaker.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't mention what type of equipment you'll be using, nor did you mention if it was an attached or detached garage.  Without a bit more detail, it's not possible to give an accurate answer. As a general guideline, you'd use 12 AWG copper conductors with a 20 ampere breaker, and 14 AWG copper conductors with a 15 ampere breaker.  Since the receptacles are in a garage, they'll have to be GFCI protected. This protection can be provided by a GFCI receptacle, or a GFCI breaker.

If you're going to be using multiple pieces of equipment that draw a lot of power, you might want to consider running a 20 ampere multi-wire branch circuit. If you have any locations where you'd use multiple high draw items together (e.g. saw and dust collection), you could install a double gang box with two duplex receptacles. Feeding each receptacle with a separate leg of the circuit, will allow you to use two high draw items without tripping the breaker.

Since it's a garage, I'd install a single 20 ampere circuit at the very least. A 15 ampere circuit would be fine for lighting, but you'll find it quite limiting when/if you start plugging in tools/equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Circuts with:

14 gauge wire = 15 amp

12 gauge wire = 20 amp

10 gauge wire = 30 amp

Be sure your circuit is GFCI protected.

Answer (score 1):

Garage outlets are often wired with #12 so that you're able to use 20A breakers, which are more suitable for heavier power equipment. If you carry through with #14, you'll be limited to a 15A breaker.

It's considered good practice (and is often required by code) to protect each outlet run with a GFCI outlet, or to protect the entire circuit with a GFCI breaker.